# Scale анимация для WPF окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Попробовал этот код:

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(1.5, 1.5);
RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
RenderTransform = scale; // Недопустимое преобразование для Window

DoubleAnimation growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
growAnimation.From = 1;
growAnimation.To = 1.8;
storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimation);

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, this);
```

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Анимацию масштабирования окна

Comment: Целиком всего окна? Вместе с заголовком и системными кнопками?

Comment: Только окна и все

Comment: Анимируйте не само окно, а корневую панель, которая в нем лежит

Comment: А по подробнее? Какая корневая панель? Grid что-ли?

Comment: Grid или что там у вас лежит